# Show only Time in status bar iOS

Tags: ios

So i only want to display the time for the status bar. Is there a way to format the status bar to only show the time, or am I going to have to just implement a time display object and hide the status bar? Any help would be great!! Thanks

Comment: I would go with your second suggestion and create your own status bar view with a time label on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to modify the status bar. You can implement a status bar of your own, but note that partially implementing a status bar is against Apple's AppStore rules and potentially unsafe (more specifically, replacing the functionality of a status bar which the users are accustomed to). For example, see [here](https://github.com/kevingibbon/KGStatusBar/issues/21):

> We found your app uses system-provided items in a non-standard manner,
>   which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we found your app animates the status bar. Please see
>   the attached screenshot for reference to the issue [screen shot shows
>   the custom status bar saying "Up To Date"].
>
> Learn more about system-provided items in the iOS Human Interface
>   Guidelines, sections: "System-Provided Buttons and Icons" and "iOS UI
>   Element Usage Guidelines."

If you still want to implement you can either hide the system status bar and a new view to each of your views, or create a new `UIWindow` with a `windowLevel` of `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1` and a frame of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame` and a label, will give you exactly what you need.